# Singly linked list in Ruby using part of code

Tags: ruby, singly-linked-list

I got a question for implementation methods like `get_item(index)`, or `find(value)` with used classes.

```
class SinglyLinkedListItem
  attr_accessor :object, :next
  attr_reader :list
  def initialize(object, list)
    @object = object
    @list = list
  end
end

class SinglyLinkedList
  attr_reader :length

  def initialize
    @length = 0
    @head = nil
    @tail = nil
  end
```

got some methods like

```
def each
    if @length > 0
      item = @head
      begin
        yield item.object
        item = item.next
      end until item.nil?
    end
  end
```

I tried with many ways, but im still getting this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `object' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: 'item = @head unless @head.nil?' From the error statement, it's saying that your head is error. Could you give us the path where you assign head with SingLyLinkedListObject?

Comment: each method is working,
but for example find

    def find(object)
        item = @head
        while item != nil
          return item if item.object == object
          item=item.next
        end
        nil
      end
not working at all... and getting error

Comment: I've written my fix, could you check the result with your compiler? Thank you.

Comment: "compiler"? Ruby isn't compiled, it's interpreted. Run your code with the `-cwW2` flag at the command-line and it'll tell you what it sees wrong syntactically.

Comment: @theTinMan: Ruby is a programming language, programming languages aren't interpreted nor compiled, they just *are*. Compilation and interpretation are traits of the compiler or interpreter (duh), not the language. BTW: with the exception of the (obsolete) MRI, all existing mainstream Ruby implementations (YARV, Rubinius, JRuby, IronRuby, MagLev, Topaz, MRuby, MacRuby) have a compiler.

Comment: I use MRI, which is still interpreted, as far as I care. Yes, languages "just are", but this is splitting hairs, when the issue was checking the result "of a compiler" instead of seeing whether there were issues with the code which would be solved by checking for warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define method `#object` on nil:

```
def nil.object; self end
```

The error will not appear that way.

Comment: humm..Advice goes to define a `single_ton` method.

Comment: It's called `voo_doo` programming paradigm.

Comment: Ohh! I see, like it.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before with attr_accessor.

Try replacing the

```
@#
```

with

```
self.#
```

And you might want to check the item class as a precaution.

```
yield item.object unless item.nil?
```

For Ex:

```
  def each
    if self.length > 0
      item = self.head
      begin
        yield item.object unless item.nil? #Check if item turned nil or not
        item = item.next
      end until item.nil?
    end
  end
```

And there might be some more handling that you need to do, but your given data doesn't provide me enough information.